# ¿Que hacer con un "stack" de Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Me surge una duda: una vez que tengas creadas las imágenes y los contenedores enlazados en un entorno de desarrollo, que se puede hacer con él?

Es decir: si quiero guardar mi entorno para descargarlo en otro ordenador como puedo hacerlo.

Me explico mejor: he creado mi entorno de desarrollo usando "docker-compose" y ahora me gustaría tenerlo disponible en cualquier máquina física.

**¿Cómo lo hago?**

Comment: Revisa los siguientes enlaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository - https://blog.giantswarm.io/moving-docker-container-images-around/ y una vez que hagas funcionar lo que necesitas, responde para colaborar con la comunidad.

Comment: Usa tu archivo `docker-compose.yml` para reconstruir tus contenedores en las maquinas que quieras.

Comment: Gracias a todos por las aportaciones. He visto que se puede exportar con docker-compose export, a un archivo .tar.gz